# Spring - PageNotFound: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: spring, servlets

I am trying to add Persual access to the functioning application

with the following URL page doesn't come up and i get http 400 bad request.

```
http://localhost:9080/ASOPartners/perusal.do
```

with the following URL  i get

```
PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ASOPartners/perusal/perusal.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'asopartners'

http://localhost:9080/ASOPartners/perusal/perusal.do
```

Here is relevant information from my new Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/perusal.do")
public String perusal(@RequestHeader(value = USERID_HEADER_KEY, required = false)   String userId,

@RequestHeader(value = COMPANYID_HEADER_KEY, required = false) String companyId,

@RequestHeader(value = "sm_serversessionId", required = false) String sessionId,

@RequestParam(value = USERID_PARAM_KEY, required = true) String appuserID,

@RequestParam(value = "companyId", required = true) String appcompID,

HttpServletRequest servletRequest,

WebRequest webRequest){

initializeUserSession(servletRequest);
```

here is my servlet mappings from Web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <description>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asoclient</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asocustomer</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asooperations</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asooperations/addcompany</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asocustomer/usermaintenance</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/asooperations/usermaintenance</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>asopartners</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/perusal</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

here is  my view controller settings

```
    <!-- YOUR ENTRIES HERE -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wellsfargo.asopartners.common.db,
                                      com.wellsfargo.asopartners.factory,
                                      com.wellsfargo.asopartners.web,
                                      com.wellsfargo.asopartners.validator,
                                      com.wellsfargo.asopartners.dao">
</context:component-scan>

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/perusal" view-name="redirect:perusal.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asocustomer" view-name="redirect:asocustomer/customer.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asocustomer/usermaintenance" view-name="redirect:usermaintenance/userMaintenance.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asoclient" view-name="redirect:asoclient/custClient.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asooperations" view-name="redirect:asooperations/operator.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asooperations/usermaintenance" view-name="redirect:usermaintenance/userMaintenance.do"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/asooperations/addcompany" view-name="redirect:addcompany/addCompany.do"/>
```

I really exausted myself trying to resolve this.It has to be something farily simple in the configurations and i am looking for help from the experts.Thank you.

Comment: Which package does method perusal in?

Comment: com.wellsfargo.asopartners.web.controller

Answer (score 0):

With the first URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/ASOPartners/perusal.do
```

The problem is that you are not passing in the `required` `@RequestParam` attributes as a query parameters with the URL. They are set as `required = true`. Hence the `400 Bad Request`.

With the second URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/ASOPartners/perusal/perusal.do
```

There is no mapping anywhere in your configuration to resolve that URL. That is, your controller method is bound to `/perusal.do`, and not `/peruslal/perusal.do`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Bhashit!I am new to the servlets and Spring and help is greatly appreciated